# Magento2 cms page display 404 via mysql query import data to cms_pgae

Tags: cms-pages, page

In Magento CE 2.4.5, I imported the page data in the cms_page table by sql, and 404 appeared in the access address. What should I do if the page cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not imported the data correctly.

CMS pages data resides in two main tables, i.e. **cms_page** and **cms_page_store**.

In order to fix the problem, you would need to import data of both tables correctly.

Also, you need to make sure that after importing, **cms_page_store** has the correct value of **page_id** corresponding to the **cms_page** table.

Answer (score 0):

For importing cms_page data best way to collect sample data(or export) make the changes and import the same file.
Two tables are where your data shall go :

cms_page :
page_id smallint Auto Increment Entity ID
title   varchar(255) NULL   Page Title
page_layout varchar(255) NULL   Page Layout
meta_keywords   text NULL   Page Meta Keywords
meta_description    text NULL   Page Meta Description
identifier  varchar(100) NULL   Page String Identifier
content_heading varchar(255) NULL   Page Content Heading
content mediumtext NULL Page Content
creation_time   timestamp [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]   Page Creation Time
update_time timestamp [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]   Page Modification Time
is_active   smallint [1]    Is Page Active
sort_order  smallint [0]    Page Sort Order
layout_update_xml   text NULL   Page Layout Update Content
custom_theme    varchar(100) NULL   Page Custom Theme
custom_root_template    varchar(255) NULL   Page Custom Template
custom_layout_update_xml    text NULL   Page Custom Layout Update Content
layout_update_selected  varchar(128) NULL   Page Custom Layout File
custom_theme_from   date NULL   Page Custom Theme Active From Date
custom_theme_to date NULL   Page Custom Theme Active To Date
meta_title  varchar(255) NULL   Page Meta Title

and

cms_page_store :
page_id smallint    Entity ID
store_id    smallint unsigned   Store ID

So important things :
in cms_page_store table there is a mapping between Store ID and page ID. Do check they are there.

in cms_page : make sure that Identifier and is_active is properly imported.
plus page id relates to cms_page_store

As these are pretty small tables and not complex I feel this is the faster way to debug and fix.